# How to get android application name from apk file

Tags: android

How do I get the android application name from a apk file programatically outside an android environment? I have tried parsing androidmanifest.xml but it only shows the package name ( which may not be very informative at times)

Comment: It won't generally be stored in the Manifest, that usually points to a string resource, typically in strings.xml...

Comment: where might i find this strings.xml?

Comment: Generally in the res/ folder, if you have an APK, then it's just a zip file.

Comment: doesn't seem to be there, maybe it isn't standard across all apk files?

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: you want to get application name from apk,using some software etc?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Linux, this command will give you the application name:

```
aapt dump badging your.apk | sed -n "s/^application-label:'\(.*\)'/\1/p"
```

You'll have to install `aapt` first.

Comment: aapt can be found in build-tools

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done with apktool.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then echo ${0##*/} useage: ${0##*/} /path/to/your.apk; exit; fi
APKTOOL=$(which apktool apktool.sh | head -1); if [ -z "$APKTOOL" ]; then echo "Error: Could not locate apktool wrapper script."; exit; fi
TMPDIR="/tmp/apktool"
rm -Rf $TMPDIR
$APKTOOL d -q -f -s --force-manifest -o $TMPDIR $1
LABEL=$(cat $TMPDIR/res/values/strings.xml | grep 'string name="title"' | sed -e 's/.*">//' -e 's/<.*//')
rm -Rf $TMPDIR
echo ${LABEL}
```